# Why is the Wordpress wp_nav_menu empty on search.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

For some reason my nav walker in Wordpress is spitting out empty items for the menu, but only on the search.php page. Here's a sample of the output:

```
    <nav class="main-nav" role="navigation">
         <div class="menu">
           <ul>
             <li id="menu-item-1671"><a target="_blank"><span>→</span></a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-3022"><a target="_blank"><span>→</span></a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-3024"><a target="_blank"><span>→</span></a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-2816"><a target="_blank"><span>→</span></a></li>

             <!-- etc... -->

          </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

And here is the code that generates the html:

```
<nav class="main-nav" role="navigation">
      <?php  
           wp_nav_menu(array(  
                  'menu' => 'Main Menu', 
                  'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
                  'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()
            )); 
      ?>
</nav>
```

And here is the nav walker code in functions.php:

```
class CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';        
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

So again, this works perfectly on every page except search.php. The only thing I can think of is that maybe this code from header.php (which of course is called by search.php) is conflicting with the namespace somehow:

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] != ''):
                $filters = explode(',',$_GET['filter']);
        else:
                $filters = array();
        endif;
        if(is_search()):
    ?>

<div class="advanced-search <?php if(!empty($filters)) echo 'open'; ?>">

        <div class="primary-filter row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span class="label">FILTER BY:</span>

                <ul class="filter-list primary">
                    <li data-target="application"><a id="application-link" href="#">Research Area</a></li>
                    <li data-target="focus-area"><a id="focus-area-link" href="#">Focus Area</a></li>
                    <li data-target="type"><a id="content-type-link" href="#">Content Type</a></li>
                    <li data-target="labs"><a id="labs-link" href="#">Lab</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="secondary-filter row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p class="filter-list" style="display:inline-block; color:#bbb;">Please select a filter category above</p>
                <ul class="filter-list" id="application">
                    <?php

                        $termlist = get_terms('application', array('hide_empty'=>0));
                        foreach($termlist as $term){
                            $class = '';
                            $slug = $term->taxonomy . "|" . $term->term_id . "|" . $term->name;
                            $id = $term->taxonomy . "_" . $term->term_id;
                            if(in_array($slug, $filters)) $class = 'hidden';
                            echo '<li data-id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'"><a href="#" data-slug="'.$slug.'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                        }

                    ?>
                </ul>

                // ...two more of these category filters here...

                <ul class="filter-list" id="type">
                    <?php
                        global $post_icons;
                        $termlist = $post_icons;
                        foreach($termlist as $term=>$icon){
                            if($term == "") continue;
                            $class = '';
                            $slug = "type|" . $term;
                            $id = "type_" . $term;
                            if(in_array($slug, $filters)) $class = 'hidden';
                            echo '<li data-id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'"><a href="#" data-slug="'.$slug.'">' . ucfirst($term) . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

            // show last-selected filter after submit

        ?>

        <div class="selection row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span class="label">APPLIED FILTERS  (click to remove)</span>

                <ul class="filter-list selections">
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($filters)):
                    foreach($filters as $f):
                        $f = explode('|', $f);
                        if($f[2]) {
                            $text = $f[2];
                            $id = $f[0] . "_" . $f[1];
                            $slug = $f[0] . "|" . $f[1] . "|" . $f[2];
                        } else {
                            $text = $f[1];
                            $id = "type_" . $f[1];
                            $slug = "type|" . $f[1];
                        }
                        echo '<li data-id="'.$id.'" class=""><a href="#" data-slug="'.$slug.'">'.ucwords($text).'</a></li>';
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Anyone ever have this happen before? Can you see what I'm missing?

*EDIT* Added code after is_search()

So I finally got debugging working on the development server (search doesn't work on my local) and it looks like these two lines are causing the error (near the end of the nav walker code):

```
>> $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

>> $item_output .= $args->after;
```

Here is the error they are throwing:

**Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php**

Comment: Have you first of all checked whether things change if you don’t use your own custom nav-walker …?

Comment: Yes, I tried reverting to the original and it just ends up empty at that point, as in, no html whatsoever.

Comment: What's after the `if(is_search()):` code block? That seems particularly relevant...

Comment: Cale_b, I updated it with the additional code.